# How to test Cadence logger call?

Tags: go, cadence-workflow

An activity instantiates a logger with `logger := activity.GetLogger(ctx)`. It's type is `*zap.Logger`.

Later, the activity calls `logger.Info("some message", zap.String("someField", some.Field))`.

How do I write a test to verify the `logger` was called in that way?

I've tried [`MockLogger`](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/common/log/mockLogger.go) but haven't found a way not to run into type issues. Do `zap.Logger` and `MockLogger` share any common (but not too generic) `interface`?

Comment: Can you give more information about the MockLogger that you have tried?

Comment: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/common/log/mockLogger.go -- I've just now added the link to OP.

Comment: Got it. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The MockLogger you are trying is in server repo, not for golang client.

You should use `testsuite. NewTestActivityEnvironment`
It provide creating a test worker env with options. And then you can register a callback(Hooks) for the zapLogger for asserting the logs(If you need to assert).

Here is the code:

```golang
func Test_Activity_Print_Logger(t *testing.T) {
    testSuite := &testsuite.WorkflowTestSuite{}
    env := testSuite.NewTestActivityEnvironment()

    // you can choose what ever you used in your production code when creating worker with workerOptions. 
    logger, err := zap.NewProduction()
    require.Nil(t, err)

    var outputLogs []string
    logger = logger.WithOptions(zap.Hooks(
        func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
            outputLogs = append(outputLogs, entry.Message)
            return nil
        },
    ))

    env.SetWorkerOptions(worker.Options{
        Logger: logger,
    })
    env.RegisterActivity(sampleActivity)

    val, err := env.ExecuteActivity(sampleActivity)

    require.Nil(t, err)
    require.True(t, !val.HasValue())
    require.True(t, len(outputLogs)==1)
    require.True(t, outputLogs[0] == "test logging")
}

func sampleActivity(ctx context.Context) error {
    logger := activity.GetLogger(ctx)
    logger.Info("test logging")
    return nil
}

func Test_Activity_Noop_Logger(t *testing.T) {
    testSuite := &testsuite.WorkflowTestSuite{}
    env := testSuite.NewTestActivityEnvironment()
    env.RegisterActivity(sampleActivity)
    val, err := env.ExecuteActivity(sampleActivity)
    require.Nil(t, err)
    require.True(t, !val.HasValue())
}
```

Also post a [PR in the sample repo](https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/pull/44).

Comment: How would the logger for the workflow itself be set?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You can’t set the logger for workflow directly . You can only provide a zap logger via WorkerOption. And client will wrap it into a workflow logger so that the logging is deterministic